# Is there a way to make current class point to the new object that has just been read in Java Serializable?

Tags: java, file, object, serializable

I am trying to read an object for a SocialNetwork Simulation. The read methods makes use of Java Serializable. The code looks like this:

```
public class SocialNetwork  implements Serializable{

// lots of fields

public SocialNetwork(){
//lots of inilization
} 
    public void writethisObject() throws IOException{
            ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("Simulation.bin"));
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(this);
        }

        public void readfromObject(File f) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
            ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
            SocialNetwork newSocialNetwork = (SocialNetwork) objectInputStream.readObject();
            this = newSocialNetwork;
        }

}
```

However as you can see I am trying to make the current class point to the object that I just read by making this = newSocialNetwork. This gives me an error as expected. I can work around this by making each and every field of the current SocialNetwork class to the newSocialNetwork. However, I do not want to do that as there are tons of field in my class. And it would look very messy. I hope you have got the idea of what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you cannot override this in Java and you want to have only one instance of your class use a [Singelton Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern):

```
public class SocialNetwork  implements Serializable{
    // lots of fields

    private static SocialNetwork myself = new SocialNetwork();

    private SocialNetwork(){ // private constructor
        //lots of inilization
    }

    public static SocialNetwork getInstance() { 
        return myself; 
    }

    public void writethisObject() throws IOException{...}

    public void readfromObject(File f) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
        ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
        myself = (SocialNetwork) objectInputStream.readObject();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for Introducing me to this. I am using a very slightly different approach to your answer. I am posting that approach in my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, but instead you can declare a static method.

```
 public static SocialNetwork readfromObject(File f) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
            ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
            return (SocialNetwork) objectInputStream.readObject();

        }
```

Comment: This wouldn't make my current class equal to the SocialNetwork that has been returned? Would it?

Comment: current class no, but this would return an instance of SocialNetwork

Comment: please describe why would you like to reassign `this`?

Comment: I understand Java limitations. The point of writing 'this' in my question is to let you know what I want to achieve. I want to make modify the current class by replacing it with the new one.

Comment: And I do not have multiple instances of SocialNetwork in our project. That's just one model. Only one instance. So every change has to be done on it.

Comment: so are you looking for a way to refresh the model from the objectInputStream?

Comment: Yes I am trying to refresh this socialnetwork model everytime it reads in a new one. Basically a load/save feature in my program. So I can resume and continue simulation

Comment: But can't you just call a static method when the user loads the state??? User probably does not need a 'refresh', but 'load' functionality. Just refactor the code so that when user loads the state the static method gets called

Answer (score 0):

We can use Singelton Pattern to achieve. Classes outside SocialNetwork will use use SocialNetwork.getInstance() to initialize the SocialNetwork. Here is the code

```
public class SocialNetwork  implements Serializable{

    // lots of fields   
    private static SocialNetwork myself = null;


    private SocialNetwork(){
    //lots of inilization
    } 


    public static SocialNetwork getInstance() { 

        if (myself == null){
            myself = new SocialNetwork();
        }
        return myself; 
    }


    public void writethisObject() throws IOException{
            ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("Simulation.bin"));
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(this);
        }

        public void readfromObject(File f) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
            ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
            SocialNetwork newSocialNetwork = (SocialNetwork) objectInputStream.readObject();
            myself = newSocialNetwork;
        }

}
```